# How to disable USSD notifications?

Tags: notifications, 4.2-jelly-bean, sim-card, notification-bar, ussd

On Android 4.2.1, some new stuff has appeared in the notification area. It shows my current balance and has an icon of the "SIM-card menu" app. Also, sometimes, some spammy messages appears (from my operator) that look like response to standard USSD request. On a previous OS, there was no such behavior.

How can I disable this? Is it OS or operator-related stuff?

Comment: What country are you in, and what's your operator? It may be a operator-related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This (at least the USSD messages) are operator related, and can only be disabled by your operator.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Also, I want to add, that there is some kind of bug in the Sim-menu app, since the mentioned notification (with balance) was sent once, and there is no way to remove it from notification bar, except rebooting device.

Comment: Just an idea: If your device is running 4.1 or higher, long-tap the entry in the notification area, tap "app info", and uncheck the box which allows that app to place notifications. That should give you some peace again.

Answer (score 2):

If you have root, you can install the XPosed Framework and install the [Ussd blocker](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-4/themes-apps/app-ussd-blocker-stop-prepaid-balance-t2603487) module.