# Block USSD carrier notification

Tags: root-access, ussd

My carrier, Vodafone, sends multiple spam popups every day via USSD like the following image:

[image: popup example]

I am rooted with EdXposed installed. Pixel 2 XL with Android 11 but willing to downgrade to Android 10 if needed.

I have tried to disable the SIM toolkit but it did not stop these pesky popups.

I have enrolled in the Do Not Disturb list by the carrier, but is there anything that I can control on my end?

Comment: Did you try their customer support? What did they suggest?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of: [Is there a way to block USSD balance notifications (on Android 4.3)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/51875/44325), [How to disable USSD notifications?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/37294/44325)

Comment: @Firelord customer support wass clueless and not helpful at all.

Comment: @AndrewT. that method is for android 4 and very old. i tried anyway but not working as expected

Comment: so far there has been no answer to this, maybe one day a hero can answer it, i can only hope